# gcc showing errors from system library. -isystem doesnt work

Tags: c++, unix, gcc

Here is a simple **(Deliberately wrong)** c++ hello world program(https://pastebin.com/Cehm9yLx)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a;
    cout >>  "Hello World! Welcome!" << endl;
    cin << a;
}
```

but when i compile it with gcc it shows me 100s of errors instead of usual 1 or 2 in my code, rest all errors are from system libraries on which i have no control. 
here is gcc output (https://pastebin.com/uTavsq43). I even tried adding **-isystem** but it still gives me errors. as the size of my code increases system errors increases too thus making me very difficult to find my problems. I tried ubuntu 17.10 and solus (both ship with **gcc 7.2**) and both have same problem. Any help will be appreciated. thanks.
Here is also simple makefile i use. (https://pastebin.com/v5Zk4M25)

Comment: The vast majority of standard header stuff in that error log is just candidates for `operator<<` and `operator>>` that it lists when none of them match (identified by them being notes instead of errors and the word "candidate" in the notes). The first thing in the error list points to the part of your code that is wrong, and the other big error in there points to the other part of your code that is wrong.

Comment: `cout <<` and `cin >>`

Comment: @chris do you have any script or any method to hide notes? it makes coding very cumbersome, especially for me because i am still a beginner.

Comment: @user9180468, The notes are part of an error or warning. If the whole thing is too long, it's probably better to fix one and compile again.

Answer (score 0):

When gcc (or clang) emits errors it does so to stderr.

You will note that the error messages have the word "error:" in them and the lines with notes have the word "note:" in them.

If only there was some means of running a command and filtering its stderr...

```
$ gcc nod.cpp 2>&1 | grep "error:"
```

Result (in my case):

````
nod.cpp:6:10: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'const char *')

nod.cpp:7:9: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('istream' (aka 'basic_istream<char>') and 'int')```
````

In bash-ese, `2>&1` means "redirect stderr to stdout"

Comment: Thankyou. this gets most of the job done but it shows 'notes:' from the **system_error** library.

Comment: Thankyou, I solved the error by replacing 'error:' by './Sources' (that is where i store my source code).

Comment: @user9180468 great. glad to have helped.